# How to avoid rewriting identical using statements?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nested, using, idisposable

Is there a way to create a nested using in a `Disposable` object, so this code:

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    ctx.Connection.Open();
    using (var tx = dbContext.Connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // ... do awesome things here

        ctx.SaveChanges();
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

to something like this:

```
using (var txContext = new TransactionContext())
{
    // ... do awesome things here
}
```

?

Currently I have:

```
public class TransactionContext : IDisposable
{
    private MyEntities DbContext { get; set; }
    private DbTransaction Transaction { get; set; }

    public TransactionContext()
    {
        DbContext = new MyEntities();
        DbContext.Connection.Open();

        Transaction = DbContext.Connection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
            Transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Transaction.Rollback();
            DbContext.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is correct in ways of disposing the different `Disposables`, especially in case of an error/exception.

Comment: I'd say the main problem with this design is that it's using the disposable pattern for more than just disposing.  If an exception happens in your `using` then `Dispose` will be called and now you are calling `SaveChanges` and `Commit` when you probably shouldn't.  Please read the MSDN article on the [dispose pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=VS.110).aspx)

Comment: Side note: do not just *swallow* exceptions: `catch (Exception) {... throw;}`

Comment: @juharr: Valid point. Did you have any other solution in mind? At the end it is just to save me from writing the same lines over and over again

Comment: @KingKerosin I've done something similar, but instead of a class I create a method that contained the basic template and took a `Action`.  Then you just write the code that is different as a lambda and pass it to the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be better to use a method instead of a class for this.

```
private static void RunInTransaction(Action<MyEntities, DbTransaction> action)
{
    using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
    {
        ctx.Connection.Open();
        using (var tx = ctx.Connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            action(ctx, tx);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            tx.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this.

```
RunInTransaction((ctx,tx) => 
{
    // ... do awesome things here
});
```

You can also create a version of this that returns a value

```
private static T RunInTransactionAndReturn<T>(
    Func<MyEntities, DbTransaction, T> function)
{
    using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
    {
        ctx.Connection.Open();
        using (var tx = ctx.Connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var result = function(ctx, tx);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            tx.Commit();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this.

```
var result = RunInTransactionAndReturn((ctx,tx) => 
{
    // ... do awesome things here
    return someResult;
});
```

Comment: I will go this (method-based) way. Thanks

Comment: @KingKerosin you should be aware that it's impossible to use ref and our parameters inside lambdas. I would stick to your IDisposable method instead.

Comment: @Vlad There's nothing here about `ref` or `out` parameters and IMHO you should avoid `ref` and `out`, not lambdas.

Comment: @juharr "There's nothing here about ref or out" I just said that in case one wants to use them it would be impossible to do so inside lamdas. IMHO you should expect any language features to be used in some situations and avoid blocking them.